# What this means in PHP, used in OpenCart: $_['SomeName'] = 'SomeValue';

Tags: php, variables, opencart

What kind of variable is this in PHP `$_['entry_store'] = 'Stores:';` used in OpenCart

Is used for saving string of text.

For example like this... 
Is it a global variable, or what is it ? it begins with `$_['SomeName];`

```
<?php
$_['heading_feedback']= 'Feedback';
$_['heading_feedback_author']= 'Feedback';
$_['text_success'] = 'Success: You have modified feedback!';
$_['text_default'] = 'Default';
```

Comment: In my opinion they should have done it this way:
return array('heading_feedback' => 'Feedback', ...etc);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not a global variable. It's a regular variable with the name `_`, and it's an array.

```
$_ = array();
$_['array_key'] = 'value';
```

Variables can be named in almost any way, the only limitation is the parser, and `_` is not a character that blocks that (for example `${0}` is a valid variable declaration)

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

Answer (score 3):

PHP doesn't prevent the variable `$_` from being an array. For example,

```
$_ = array('foo' => 'bar');
echo $_['foo']; // bar
```

works correctly, as does `$_foo` or any other non-reserved name.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go back to basics. A snippet from [**the docs**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).

> A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores

The variable `$_` is not a global variable, it's a regular one (with a poor naming convention).

Comment: +1 for poor naming convention, but that is different story in OpenCart :-)